# get_the_excerpt() not returning anything when post has no excerpt

Tags: functions, excerpt, the-content, tags

When trying to call `get_the_excerpt()` the page does not return anything on posts that have no excerpt.

I thought WordPress usually 'fake' it and create one using the first x characters from `the_content()`.

Or have things changed?

Answer (score 2):

Double check that you don't have a check for `has_excerpt()` that's hiding the "auto-generated" excerpt. Even if `get_the_excerpt()` returns something made from `post_content`, `has_excerpt()` still returns false if the excerpt is empty.

If that's not the case, see if there's a function that filters on `get_the_excerpt` that could be effecting this.

To answer your question, [`wp_trim_excerpt()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2096), the function that "fakes" an excerpt, [filters `get_the_content()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L147) which [`the_excerpt()` is just a wrapper](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L240) function for. So that's not the issue.

Comment: Theres no has_excerpt() condition before I print get_the_excerpt(). Although I have still checked the functions file and there is nothing that I can see that could be filtering get_the_excerpt.

Comment: Does it work if you use `the_excerpt()`?

Comment: Also having this problem - is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had,

```
function mytheme_excerpt_length() {
  return POST_EXCERPT_LENGTH;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length','mytheme_excerpt_length');
```

and `POST_EXCERPT_LENGTH` was defined somewhere, which got deleted by mistake. So, excerpt was returning 0 characters.

So, just return a value greater than `0` and it should fix the issue.