# Nothing appears using get_the_excerpt() in category.php

Tags: posts, categories, content, excerpt

Using the category.php template file and I can get all other information about a post except the excerpt or the content.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
$cat = get_queried_object();
$posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 15, 'offset' => 0, 'category' => $cat->term_id));

                foreach($posts as $post)
                {
                    $postID = $post->ID;
                    $title = get_the_title($postID);
                    $link = get_permalink($postID);
                    $date = get_the_date('M. j, Y', $postID);
                    $authors = coauthors_posts_links(null, null, null, null, false);
                    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($postID);
                    $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post, array('class' => 'front-page-tease-sm'));

                    echo '<div class="category-post">';

                    // Left box - date
                    printf('<div class="date">%1$s</div>', esc_attr($date));

                    // Middle box flex - headline, author, and excerpt
                    echo '<div class="category-post-info">';
                    printf('<a class="category-headline" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>', esc_attr($link), esc_html($title));
                    printf('<div class="category-author">By %1$s</div>', $authors);
                    printf('<div class="category-tease">%1$s</div>', $excerpt);
                    echo '</div>';

                    // Right box - thumbnail
                    printf($thumb);

                    echo '</div>';
                }
```

This code does exactly what I expect it to do except for when it comes to excerpts.  It prints nothing for the excerpt, not even HTML tags.

Comment: Just try this and let me know. `$excerpt =apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_id));` instead of `$excerpt = get_the_excerpt($postID);`

Comment: No luck with that either

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/152133/106350 Read this answer also

Comment: I added that function but still nothing.  I printed the length of $excerpt and it's coming out as 0.

Comment: Do you have debugging turned on? And if do a data dump on your $post objects does post_content or post_excerpt have any data?

Comment: I do not - how can I turn on debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the code. There are some issues in your code :

1. There is not any method 'coauthors_posts_links' but WordPress provides a method [the_author_posts_link();](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link).
2. Also for the 'get_the_post_thumbnail()' function 2nd parameter must be image size like

   ```
   $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post, 'thumbnail',array('class' => 'front-page-tease-sm'));
   ```

I have updated the code. For 'coauthors_posts_links()' no idea what you want to do here ?

```
$cat = get_queried_object();
$posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 15, 'offset' => 0, 'category' => 1));

                foreach($posts as $post)
                {
                    $postID = $post->ID;
                    $title = get_the_title($postID);
                    $link = get_permalink($postID);
                    $date = get_the_date('M. j, Y', $postID);
                    $authors = '';
                    $excerpt = get_the_excerpt($postID);
                    $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post, 'thumbnail',array('class' => 'front-page-tease-sm'));

                    echo '';

                    // Left box - date
                    printf('%1$s', esc_attr($date));

                    // Middle box flex - headline, author, and excerpt
                    echo '';
                    printf('%2$s', esc_attr($link), esc_html($title));
                    printf('By %1$s', $authors);
                    printf('%1$s', $excerpt);
                    echo '';

                    // Right box - thumbnail
                    printf($thumb);

                    echo '';
                }
```

Comment: coauthors_posts_links() is a function from a plugin, and is irrelevant to this question.

The issue is with the excerpt, and **only with the excerpt**.  The code you "fixed" does not resolve this issue.

Comment: Hey Mike, for someone asking for free help, this was a bit rude.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is extremely frustrating to ask a question and then have someone completely ignore it and give a totally irrelevant answer that helps nothing.

Comment: did my code below help?

Comment: @Mike I executed your code and the issues I have found mentioned above. 'get_the_excerpt() ' worked fine on my side except 'get_the_post_thumbnail()' which have issue. I mentioned in the answer. You can use the <a href=''https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/'>Query Monitior<a/> plugin for debugging. Also, there will be a log will under wp-content folder. https://tommcfarlin.com/viewing-the-php-debug-log/ check the post for enabling debugging in wordpress

Comment: I'm not getting any php errors related to the excerpt, according to Query Monitor.

Comment: have you checked your post have the post_excerpt in db ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say you have a filter running on the excerpt.

Have you tried just echoing it instead of print?

```
<?php echo 'here is my excerpt: '.$excerpt;?>
```

Also if there is a filter somewhere and you can't find it, you could try:

```
//$excerpt = get_the_excerpt(); // This doesn't work

// Let's do it like the get_the_excerpt filter function in the core does
// Get Excerpt directly without filters.
$excerpt = $post->post_excerpt;

// Choose what to do based on whether it's empty or not
if ($excerpt != '') echo $excerpt;
else echo 'some fallback';
```

Comment: I've tried echoing with no luck.  Your other suggestion didn't work either.